# How to set the orientation of menu items to the right?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, menu

How do I make a certain menuitem's horizontal alignment set to right like the following?

[image]

Setting HorizontalAlignment="Right" in XAML wasn't the answer. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this layout help you?

```
   <Menu Height="20" >
                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="three"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit">
                    <MenuItem Header="two"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Tools">
                    <MenuItem Header="one"/>
                </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Help" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <MenuItem Header="zero"/>
                    </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
```

Looks as your example.